# Getting error no such file or directory in node js

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am new here in node js, so i am sorry for this issue, I need to rebuild and run webpack, for that i have 2 commands here is that

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --optimize-minimize",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --hot-inline"
  },
```

Where i run this `NODE_ENV=production ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --optimize-minimize` command it says `file or directory not found` can anyone please help me how can i get rid of that ?

Comment: have you tried running the command in the console, see what happens? Does the actual file `./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js` exist?

Comment: Try `npm install`

Comment: @MagdKudama i don't , i am new in nodejs

Comment: @Vaibhav npm is already installed

Comment: it doesn't matter whether you're new to NodeJS. Open a terminal and run the command `NODE_ENV=production ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --optimize-minimize`. What do you see?

Comment: @MagdKudama it says no such file

Comment: Can you list if there's content on your `node_modules` folder?

Comment: @MagdKudama Can you please tell  me command for that ?

Comment: My question is fairly simple: do you have a node_modules folder in the root of the project? If so, what does it contain?

Comment: @MagdKudama no i don't have that folder

Comment: You need to run `npm install` in the root of your project. I'm assuming you have a `package.json` file in the root.

Comment: @MagdKudama thanks let me try for it

Comment: @MagdKudama its working now thanks a lot for your help